# argparse, two arguments depend on each other

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to make the parser like `cmd [-a xxx -b xxx] -c xxx -d xxx`

When `-a` is used, I want `-b` to be used too. likewise, if `-b` is used, `-a` must be used too. It's ok both `-a` and `-b` are not used.

How do I do that? I have tried custom actions, but it does not go well.

Answer (score 14):

A better design would be to have a single option that takes two arguments:

```
parser.add_argument('-a', nargs=2)
```

Then you either specify the option with 2 arguments, or you don't specify it at all.

```
$ script -a 1 2
```

or

```
$ script
```

A custom action (or postprocessing) can split the tuple `args.a` into two separate values `args.a` and `args.b`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks a good idea, I finally used nargs=2 in my program.

Comment: It is indeed `nargs` not `narg` but I can't edit the answer because it's only 1 char

Comment: In my case a and b are of different types and have different default values so I cant use this solution

Answer (score 12):

Argparse doesn't natively support this type of use.

The most effective thing to do is check and see if those types of conditions are met after parsing:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-b')
parser.add_argument('-c')

args = parser.parse_args()

required_together = ('b','c')

# args.b will be None if b is not provided
if not all([getattr(args,x) for x in required_together]):
    raise RuntimeError("Cannot supply -c without -b")
```

Comment: This looks correct.  I'm adding the phrase "mutually inclusive arguments" here in the hope that others searching that way may find it...

Comment: With this solution, you cannot run the code without providing both `-b` and `-c`, i.e. you can't even run it with no options at all, which is not desirable I think, in general with **optional** arguments, but also relative to what the OP was asking: _"It's ok both -a and -b are not used."_.